# Conversion of Marks into GPA using pattern matching in scala

Tags: scala, match

I am trying to write Scala function that takes marks and return GPA based on defined criteria. I am using pattern matching but pattern matching works if case has single value like case 50 => 1, but I am unable to get desired results as i want, like return GPA 1 if marks are equal to or greater than 50 and less than 58. My code is here.

```
def convertor(marks : Int) : Int = marks match {
    case marks if marks < 50 => 0 
    case marks if marks >= 50 && marks < 58 =>  1
    case marks if marks >= 58 && marks < 70 =>  2
    case marks if marks >= 70 && marks < 85 =>  3
    case marks if marks >= 85  => 4
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo when asking but it should be `case  marks if marks >= 50 && marks < 58 =>  1` _(note the **if**)_. Maybe that is the problem? Also what is the purpose of the last case? Isn't `marks >= 85` enough?, BTW, you are missing a case for values lower than 50 _(which right now will have a value of 4, which I doubt is what you want)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez please check now. I want to not use if block here, using if is simpler just use if, else if and else, I want to only use case with match

Comment: It is not an if block, it is a pattern guard, take a look to https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html  - I will edit your question with the appropriate syntax.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks

Answer (score 2):

Every `case` creates a new temporary variable which, in this case, you don't actually need. So you could do this:

```
def convertor(marks : Int) : Int = marks match {
  case _ if marks < 50 => 0
  case _ if marks >= 50 && marks < 58 =>  1
  case _ if marks >= 58 && marks < 70 =>  2
  case _ if marks >= 70 && marks < 85 =>  3
  case _ if marks >= 85  => 4  
}
```

Or, as @LeoC aptly points out:

```
def convertor(marks : Int) : Int = marks match {
  case _ if marks < 50 => 0
  case _ if marks < 58 => 1
  case _ if marks < 70 => 2
  case _ if marks < 85 => 3
  case _               => 4  
}
```

But that's little better than sequencing `if`/`else if` tests. I'd be inclined to try something like this:

```
def convertor(marks : Int) : Int =
  Seq(50, 58, 70, 85, Int.MaxValue).indexWhere(marks < _)
```

Comment: both pieces of code are working fine. One more question with performance point of view which one is faster?

Comment: The 2nd one might be a _tiny_ bit faster. A `marks` value of 90 will pass through 8 tests in the 1st example but only 5 in the 2nd.

Comment: Since the integer ranges are contiguous (and Scala `case` statements do not fall through), I think all lowerbound checks can be skipped in the first snippet.